# Position of elements changes after JWplayer loads

Tags: html, css, jwplayer

I have a video loaded in jwplayer and a small video queue with thumbnails positioned right alongside it. For some reason, when my player loads, it pushes the entire queue down below the player, despite it being right next to it otherwise. It is behaving as if the container is too small, but if I make the videoWrapper larger I get the same behavior.

HTML:

```
<div id="videoWrapper">
    <div id="video"></div>  

    <script type='text/javascript'>
            jwplayer('video').setup({
                    file: <?php echo '\''.$sex.'\''?>,
                    width: '750',
                    height: '420',
                    primary: 'flash',
                    autostart: 'false'
            });
    </script>

    <div id="queueList">
        Up Next
        <input type="image" src=<?php echo $thumbs[0]; ?> class="thumb" />
        <input type="image" src=<?php echo $thumbs[1]; ?> class="thumb" />
        <input type="image" src=<?php echo $thumbs[2]; ?> class="thumb" />
        <input type="image" src=<?php echo $thumbs[3]; ?> class="thumb" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#videoWrapper{
    display:block;
    width:872px;
    height:420px;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}#queueList{
    width:120px;
    height:420px;
    float:right;
}.thumb{
    margin-top:7px;
    width:120px;
    height:auto;
    background:black;
}#video{
    width:750px;
    height:420px;
    background:black;
    color:purple;
    float:left;
}
```

If anyone can provide any sort of reason why this is happening or a work around I would very much appreciate it.

A live look at what I am talking about can be seen here: http://porndoraone.com/test2.php
The orange boxes should be inside the black border, adjacent to the video.

Comment: Please provide a link to where you are running this.

Comment: You can see the dumbed down version here : http://porndoraone.com/test2.php
It is easiest to see what is going on in safari or chrome

Comment: It seems to load the same in Chrome as Firefox, the navigation is in the lower right.

Comment: Correct, but I would like it to be adjacent to the player, inside of the black border. If you remove the source from the JWplayer you will see that it loads as intended

Comment: What if flash is set as primary?

Comment: I believe it is, is it not?

Comment: Right, so it is, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution seems to be very simple. All what you have to do is style `#video_wrapper`, created by jwplayer, like this:

```
#video_wrapper {
    float: left;
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nh3mw/) with working demo.

Comment: I have tested this and it does not appear to work.
It seems like you added not only "float:left;" but also "position:relative;". I have tried all combinations of this and it does not seem to yield the desired result.

Comment: Pavel, this is fantastic and worked like a charm. I had no idea JWPlayer created this #video_wrapper… where could I go to learn more?

Comment: I was just checking elements around your player and reveal this :-) Anyway, you are welcome.